# UIImage (from path) to NSData causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uiimage, nsdata

I have following code

```
for (int i=0; i<self.imageArray.count; i++) 
{
    [self.operation addData:[self getDataFromImage:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i]] 
    forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pa_image%d",i+1] 
    mimeType:@"image/png" 
    fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pa_image%d.png",i+1]];

}
```

From here following method is calling

```
-(NSData *)getDataFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    NSData *imageData=  UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.1);
    return imageData;
}
```

There are 2 scenarios in my code for imageArray when

1) values are coming from API in imageArray like  "images/upload/d872f1.png",  "images/upload/0fdade.png" then returning nil in NSData. I want to convert from this path to NSData. how to Do?

After executing this line  my app is crashing. It is giving

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString CGImage]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f83a1f13510'

2) When i am uploading from phone its like   " ,  {834, 1250} ”.My code is working properly in this scenario its converting into NSData.

For more details here is my addData method

```
-(void) addData:(NSData*) data forKey:(NSString*) key mimeType:(NSString*) mimeType fileName:(NSString*) fileName 
 {

  if ([self.request.HTTPMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"]) 
  {
  [self.request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 }

 NSDictionary *dict = @{@"data": data,
@"name": key,
@"mimetype": mimeType,
@"filename": fileName};

[self.dataToBePosted addObject:dict];
}
```

Comment: in your imageArray you have NSString Objects or UIImage Objects?

Comment: UIimage objects -  <__NSArrayM 0x7f83a40dd850>(
images/upload/d872f1.png,
images/upload/0fdade.png
)

Comment: i think its file names.

Comment: No its not working..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        if([[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        {

            NSString *stringFromAPI = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:stringFromAPI];

            image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]];

        }else
        {
            image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
        }
        [self.operation addData:[self getDataFromImage:image]
                         forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pa_image%d",i+1]
                       mimeType:@"image/png"
                       fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pa_image%d.png",i+1]];
```

Comment: if we use directly  image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i]]; it will give null because of directly conversion from string to image, instead of this i used                                                NSString *stringFromAPI = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i];

            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:stringFromAPI];

            image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]]; Then it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
Try This

for (int i=0; i<self.imageArray.count; i++) 
{
    UIImage *image;
    if([[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]){
     image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    }else{
     image = [self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
     }
    [self.operation addData:[self getDataFromImage:image] 
forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pa_image%d",i+1] 
mimeType:@"image/png" 
fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pa_image%d.png",i+1]];

}
```

Comment: There are 2 scenarios in my code for imageArray when 1) values are coming from API in imageArray like  "images/upload/d872f1.png",  "images/upload/0fdade.png" then ur solution returning nil in NSData  2) When i am uploading from phone its like   "<UIImage: 0x7f804b912980>, {834, 1250}”  then ur solution also crashing.

Comment: image = [UIImage imageNamed:[self.imageArray objectAtIndex:i]]; on this line image value giving null. So i updated my answer.Thank you..!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah check your array with breakpoint. It contains string and not an image.

The exception is itself explanatory.